# How to force gpu usage with JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, gpu, directx, nvidia

I use JavaFX with Java 8 and i set this properties before launching my app
`System.setProperty("prism.forceGPU","true");`
`System.setProperty("prism.order","d3d,sw");`
The verbose mode for prism gives me this :

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Threshold to enable UI scaling factor: 1.5
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
        succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 8192
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
OS Information:
        Windows version 10.0 build 19044
D3D Driver Information:
        Intel(R) HD Graphics 630
        \\.\DISPLAY1
        Driver igdumdim64.dll, version 25.20.100.6373
        Pixel Shader version 3.0
        Device : ven_8086, dev_591B, subsys_11C81462
        Max Multisamples supported: 4
 vsync: true vpipe: true
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_16
```

which shows that hardware acceleration is supported, but I have a Nvidia GTX 1050m TI perfectly installed and set up and JavaFX doesn't seem to want to use it, it's always using Intel(R) HD Graphics 630.

Is there a way to force gpu usage ?

ANSWER :

I solve the problem by simply setting java.exe default gpu to be the nvidia's one after many hours of research, it seems to work but cannot be done from the application code.

Comment: I suggest you post and accept an Answer to your own Question.

Comment: What makes you believe that such an outdated version of Java/FX would still support the latest graphics hardware? We are writing the year 2022 and Java 18 (not 8) is right on our door steps this month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are trying to solve a similar issue, it might be coming from the java.exe executable not using the gpu you want as a default device, you can change that in Windows' settings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding this answer as I believe it can help others, and also as a reminder in case I'm going to need this again someday.

**Note:** this is for Linux, I don't know if it would work on other OSes too

I have a laptop with the Intel iGPU and an NVIDIA dGPU, I use Linux (arch btw) and have `optimus-manager` set up to hybrid mode. In this configuration, JavaFX applications are not recognized to be offloaded to the dGPU and will use the iGPU instead.
On the internet there are some mentions to the `DRI_PRIME=1` config, but it is not enough.

These are all the environment variables needed to run JavaFX on the dGPU:

```
DRI_PRIME=1
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1
__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
```

Bonus: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to run my JavaFX applications, it's enough to add those options in the dedicated section in the `run` configurations like this:
[image: IntelliJ IDEA config]